# How to detect whether user have touched an area of an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have an image with transparent background. I would like to find out whether use have touched the non-transparent area of the image with CoreGraphics framework. Is this possible? Is there any resources that I can read about this?

Thanks heaps for the guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to implement the logic yourself here. You will need to [intercept the touches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281211/how-to-make-a-superview-intercept-button-touch-events) to get the coordinates in the image, get the [pixel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics) of the image and determine the alpha value, then determine if that satisfies your definition of transparent.