# How to create a view with a transparent view on it and background view touchable?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, view

[image]I need to create a view like this. Where my actionsheet like view is a subview added on viewcontroller. Its not real action sheet.
What i want to keep the controls behind the overlay view touchable also the action sheet buttons.
Can anyone suggest, How to do it ?

Comment: probably your problem is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/1281211/1030951

Comment: you can see this http://www.dbuggr.com/leothenerd/add-transparent-uitextview-cocos2d-iphone-layer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My action sheet is a custom View, I used a Button on view above the action sheet. After disabling user interaction and setting alpha .7 worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test Action Sheet" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Home",@"iPhone", nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.view];
```

Comment: Also you will need to add a delegate UIActionSheetDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Take one `UIImageView` on front of all views and set Alpha something like bellow..

```
[imgBackShadow setAlpha:0.9];// set yourImage name instead of imgBackShadow
// Also set different value to Alpha with your requirement
```

First `setHidden` to `YES` and when you want to open `UIActionSheet` at that time just `setHidden` to `NO` also set property `setUserInteractionEnabled` to `NO` like bellow..

```
[imgBackShadow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];// set yourImage name instead of imgBackShadow
```

**Example :** when you want to open `UIActionSheet` at that time use bellow code..

```
[imgBackShadow setHidden:NO];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgBackShadow];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourActionSheet];
```

and when you want to close `UIActionSheet` at that time just Hide that Image like bellow..

```
[imgBackShadow setHidden:YES];
```

hope its helpful to you..